# "Unprocessable Entity" passing data to Laravel controller via Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm trying to submit data to my Laravel Controller using Ajax, but I'm getting the error "422 (Unprocessable Entity)".

I've done some Googling, and I think it is to do with the JSON being passed, but I'm unsure how to solve it.

The following is what I believe to be the relevant info:

**Script**

```
$("#addStepNew").click(function() {
  var step_ingredients = JSON.stringify(stepIngredients)
  var step_description = $('#stepDescription').val();
  var prep_step = $('input[name=prepStep]:checked').val();

  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
    type: "post",
    data: "ingredients="+step_ingredients+"&description="+step_description+"&is_prep="+prep_step+"step_no=1",
    dataType:'json',
    url: "{{ route('ingredients.store', ['id' => $recipe->id]) }}",
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $("#output").html('<div class="alert alert-success my-0">'+data.name+' added</div>');
      $("#output").toggleClass("invisible")
      $("#output").fadeOut(2000);
    }
  });
});
```

The `console.log(stepIngredients)` gives `[{"ingredient_id":"9","ingredient_quantity":"3","Ingredient_units":"kilograms"}]`

The idea is to pass it all through to my controller, and write the values to the DB, but at the minute I can't even pass the info.

I've done the following to my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  //$this->validate($request);

  /*
  $step = new Step;
  $step->recipe_id = $request->recipe_id;
  $step->step_no = $request->step_no;
  $step->method = $request->description;
  $step->save();
  */

  $data = [
    'success' => true,
    'message'=> 'Your AJAX processed correctly',
  ] ;

  return response()->json($data);
}
```

So as I understand it (I'm teaching myself this as I go along), if the AJAX is passed successfully, then it should return the success message and output it in my `#output div`?

```
    +--------+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
    | Domain | Method    | URI                      | Name               | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
    +--------+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
    |        | GET|HEAD  | /                        |                    | App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@index                             | web          |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                 |                    | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | home                     | home               | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | login                    | login              | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest    |
    |        | POST      | login                    |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest    |
    |        | POST      | logout                   | logout             | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web          |
    |        | POST      | password/email           | password.email     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest    |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset           | password.request   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest    |
    |        | POST      | password/reset           |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest    |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}   | password.reset     | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest    |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | recipes                  | recipes.index      | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@index                           | web,auth     |
    |        | POST      | recipes                  | recipes.store      | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@store                           | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | recipes/create           | recipes.create     | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@create                          | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | recipes/{id}/ingredients | ingredients.create | App\Http\Controllers\IngredientsController@create                      | web,auth     |
    |        | POST      | recipes/{id}/ingredients | ingredients.store  | App\Http\Controllers\IngredientsController@store                       | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | recipes/{id}/steps       | steps.create       | App\Http\Controllers\StepsController@create                            | web,auth     |
    |        | POST      | recipes/{id}/steps       | steps.store        | App\Http\Controllers\StepsController@store                             | web,auth     |
    |        | PUT|PATCH | recipes/{recipe}         | recipes.update     | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@update                          | web,auth     |
    |        | DELETE    | recipes/{recipe}         | recipes.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@destroy                         | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | recipes/{recipe}         | recipes.show       | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@show                            | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | recipes/{recipe}/edit    | recipes.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\RecipesController@edit                            | web,auth     |
    |        | POST      | register                 |                    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest    |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | register                 | register           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest    |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tags                     | tags.index         | App\Http\Controllers\TagsController@index                              | web,auth     |
    |        | POST      | tags                     | tags.store         | App\Http\Controllers\TagsController@store                              | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tags/create              | tags.create        | App\Http\Controllers\TagsController@create                             | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tags/{tag}               | tags.show          | App\Http\Controllers\TagsController@show                               | web,auth     |
    |        | PUT|PATCH | tags/{tag}               | tags.update        | App\Http\Controllers\TagsController@update                             | web,auth     |
    |        | DELETE    | tags/{tag}               | tags.destroy       | App\Http\Controllers\TagsController@destroy                            | web,auth     |
    |        | GET|HEAD  | tags/{tag}/edit          | tags.edit          | App\Http\Controllers\TagsController@edit                               | web,auth     |
    +--------+-----------+--------------------------+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Can you show me route for ingredients.store in web.php

Comment: @AmmarAli updated the OP with the routes.